# css hover efect is not working properly

Tags: html, css

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u7gjgppu/),

I set, when hove on my footer list, it will display green color.

It works fine, but when hover out the list, that time time also hover effect is working.

CSS:

```
.social-bar a:hover span {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline:none;
    color: green; /* Match icon highlight color */
}
```

When will see my demo, it is going to get idea.

Comment: What do you mean? It only become green, when I am over the link. If I move out, it's disappearing.

Comment: What do you mean _out of the list_?

Comment: `.social-bar a {
    display:block;
}` this code makes the anchor(`a`) take the whole width.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay: when hover in some distance to that icon, that time also it shows green color right?

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: firefox @DavidChavez..

Comment: Do you mean hover to the right? Do you want them to be on a new line or next to each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `display: block` to `display: table`

```
.social-bar a {
  display: table;
}
```

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Manojkr/azat75n0/1/)

Comment: It is similar to block but it works for your solution. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/u7gjgppu/1/. I have updated the display from block to inline block. Also added `<br/>` to bring the anchors to next line.

```
.social-bar a {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your :hover listener is on "a" tag, this "a" tag is as wide as it parent (social-bar) which take the screen width.

try:

```
.social-bar a span:hover
```

or just limit the width of social-bar or "a" tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
.social-bar a {
  display: block;
}
```

The above CSS code made your element `block` and it occupies the `100%` width of the parent div which is `.social-bar`

So if you want to limit it to the anchor tag alone with the width of the anchor to be setted according to it's content inside just change your `hover` css like below.

```
.social-bar a span:hover {
 }
```